# web.config that worked under IIS 7.5 doesn't work under IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis-7.5, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET web site running under IIS 7.5  Works great.

Now we're experimenting with a new Windows 10 server, which runs IIS 10.  Copied the identical web site to the new server and try to open it:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
...
Error Code     0x8007000d
...
Config Source:
  -1: 
   0:
```

I [looked up](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055) the error code:

> Cause: This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config file or the Web.config file contains a malformed XML element.
>
> Resolution: Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config file or from the Web.config file.

But that web.config file has been working for years.  Nothing has changed.  So I think that "malformed xml" message is a red herring, and there must be some other setting I'm missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am running into the same issue - but haven't figured out a fix yet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was running into the exact same issue and for me it was because I forgot to install Url Rewrite 2.0 for IIS, so my rewrite rules were causing the error. Not sure if this will be the same for you or not.

I figured it out by commenting out blocks of the web.config until I got it to stop throwing that error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yip, URL Rewrite was the culprit.  Thanks!

Comment: Yay! Solved the issue for me too!

Comment: I have URL Rewrite 2.1 installed, getting the same error still =(

Comment: You're a hero, this was my issue going from an IIS 8 to IIS 10 server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was not able to found either the reason for that nor the solution. I saw the description about the rewrite module installation each times, but this has not solved my problem at all! Finally, after a few days, I came across this site:

[IIS unable to read web.config, no error details in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465004/iis-unable-to-read-web-config-no-error-details-in-message)

I followed this instruction and installed the mentioned environment on the server. After that I restarted it and lo and behold, everything worked fine :-)