# IIS unable to read web.config, no error details in message

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a dotnet core 3.1 web API application that is published to an IIS 10 hosted on a Windows 2012 R2 datacenter VM.

The application is running under an application pool that has no managed code:

[image: app pool screenshot]

IIS is not able to read the web.config. This is what I get when clicking this app's Connection Strings in IIS:

[image: IIS error]

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="" roles="mydomain\mydevrole" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="?" roles="" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Common if you forgot to install some IIS OOB components. Check https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html#oob-related-500-19-errors

Comment: On Windows 10, this did not install properly. It appeared on Start menu after installation completed, but clicking it brought up "Choose an application to open..."

Comment: Installing Jexus Manager is optional. You should focus on your web.config file and see if you forgot any OOB used inside.

Comment: Most settings are in the appsettings.json. The only thing in web.config is an authorization section. And I know authorization feature exists on that VM and working because other framework apps that rely on it are working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Installing ASP.NET Core Runtime is not enough. You have to install the [Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer).

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

[image: download page]

Comment: This is a life saving answer. THANK YOU!

Comment: I searched for the cause for a long time and found none. Especially since I did not get a concrete error code, but only a message saying that something was wrong. But just not concretely what!
Your post has led me ultimately to the solution! I installed this whole environment that you linked here and restarted the server. After that the problem was finally fixed!
Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked file permissions? Specifically has the IIS_IUSR$ group got permissions to read the folder where the website is located?
Also check the windows event logs to see if there is more information.

Comment: Try an empty web.config file from https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/815179/how-to-create-the-web-config-file-for-an-asp-net-application

Comment: Also try renaming file, and see if IIS creates one (been a while, can't remember if it does this or not)

Comment: Also, not sure if this is relevant, as I've not used dot net Core myself yet. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1
Quotes:
"ASP.NET Core no longer uses the Global.asax and web.config files that previous versions of ASP.NET utilized." 
"The web.config file has also been replaced in ASP.NET Core"

Comment: Renaming web.config helped. No new web.config was created automatically. IIS is now opening the features/properties for this app. But doing this has rendered the app useless. API routes are not working. Only static  HTML/CSS files are working. Basically IIS is just acting as a web server.